# Find broadband router configuration url

Tags: windows, mobile-broadband

I have a vodafone ZTE modem, I wish to configure it. But when I enter the modem's url or modem's default gateway the browser does not display any configuration page.

How can I get the configuration url. I tried searching for documentation, no default url. But it shure has a web interface.

Comment: command prompt… `arp -a` will show you IP addresses on the subnet. Assuming there's only a few, process of elimination wouldn't be difficult [hint: it's most likely to end in 1]

Comment: Does this help - [How do I unlock my USB modem?](http://support.vodafone.com.au/articles/FAQ/How-do-I-unlock-my-USB-modem)?